# Autodesk forge: Authenticated requests for viewer now return 403

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am working on a proof of concept item using the Autodesk Forge platform. This is a .Net MVC page using the JS library provided by Autodesk for the viewer (v2.13)

I am suddenly receiving a 403 error on requests to view a model. The model was uploaded in June and hasn't changed since for the request, I generate a new auth token on page load for the user. I am generating a token using the keys for my app and the calls still generate a token.

All requests for the data against the URI:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/(MyObjectURN)

now all attempts to load come back as a 403 with
{fault.name} - The client_id specified does not have access to the api product
as the error message
It has started in the last hour or so.

I can generate new auth tokens but it still fails on calls to get the model. Our hosted demo platform (for showing internal users not on site) code base hasn't changed in a week and exhibits the same behaviour leading me to believe it's a code change in the referenced Autodesk Forge libraries 
(such as https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.js?v=v2.13)
or a service issue on the viewer service.

I can upload cut up code (removing identifiable details, keys etc) if required

Answer (score 0):

This means that your application is using the [deprecated Viewer v1 API](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/end-life-notice-view-and-data-api).

See more at this [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-giving-error-403-unauthorized). Please take the steps to migrate your application.

Comment: I am facing this issue in version 7.8 of the viewer src= "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.js". It has been since last 3 or 4 days before that all the models were loading perfectly. But now I get 403 error(request url https://cdn.derivative.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/*) or the model partially loads in the viewer and you can see that as the event associated with model is loaded doesn't get triggered.